# How do I limit the dragging area for image views

Tags: ios, swift, draggable

My first post and I am currently making an app in Xcode 8.1 using Swift 3

I have 9 images that I have made draggable with touchesBegan and touchesMoved functions.

However they are able to be dragged ANYWHERE on the screen and this can cause them to cover up other images I have. I would like to limit their movement by setting a boundary for them so that even when the user tries to drag the images out of that boundary they wont be able to.

I have created this code in draggedimageview.swift this allows the Image views to be dragged.

I have been spending a long time trying to figure out how to do this and if anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Thanks...

```
import UIKit

class DraggedImageView: UIImageView {

    var startLocation: CGPoint?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        startLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let currentLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self)
        let dx = currentLocation!.x - startLocation!.x
        let dy = currentLocation!.y - startLocation!.y

        self.center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x+dx, y: self.center.y+dy)
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you set self.center, look at what you are about to set it to and change it based on your boundary. Show us your attempt.

Comment: Excellent first post! Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
let cx = self.center.x+dx
if (cx > 100) {
   cx = 100
}

self.center = CGPoint(x: cx, y: self.center.y+dy)
```

But alter the if based on what you are trying to do.  This clamps it so that it cannot be moved to a position where `center.x > 100`

Comment: Thanks, where would I need to put this in the current code I have written in order for it to work? Also what does cx refer to? I'm very new to Xcode and programming in general.

Comment: Where ever you set the center normally.  In the code you showed, it was in touchesMoved

Comment: Would I have to use this code instead of certain code I used or in addition to?

Comment: I tried using that code and it does seem to constrain it but only constrains it to the left side of the screen just left of the centre I think

Comment: I was giving you an example -- you need to finish it based on the example. `if cx > 100` means if the center.x is greater than 100.  If it is, it sets it to 100.  That means if you go left of 100, it stops it at 100. Now, write the equivalent for the right side.  For the top and bottom, you need to make a cy that is center.y + dy and do something similar

Comment: Thanks I thought hard about it and finally got it to work. The images now stay within the boundaries I wanted. I have been trying to get the app to work on any device (as in using constraints to get everything to fit each apple device properly) but that hasn't worked and the boundaries I set here work only on certain devices. But the boundaries work for the device I built the app for

Answer (score 1):

Try to define your "allowed area" in a rect, such as:

```
import UIKit

class DraggedImageView: UIImageView {

    var startLocation: CGPoint?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        startLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let currentLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self)
        let dx = currentLocation!.x - startLocation!.x
        let dy = currentLocation!.y - startLocation!.y

        // This is the area in which the dragging is allowed
        let coolArea = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

        let newCenter = CGPoint(x: self.center.x+dx, y: self.center.y+dy)

        // If the allowed area contains the new point, we can assign it
        if coolArea.contains(newCenter) {
            self.center = newCenter
        }
        // else {
        //    print("Out of boundaries!")
        // }

        self.center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x+dx, y: self.center.y+dy)
    }
}
```

You may want to change the code if you want something different to happen when user is dragging out of the bounds.

Comment: So would I need to add this code to my current code? I'm just struggling to understand what this code actually does.

Comment: So would I need to add this code to my current code? I'm just struggling to understand what this code actually does. coolArea would be the rectangle boundary in which I want to keep the images within wouldn't it. So would I need to write this on top of my current code or would I need to change some?

Comment: refined the example, check it out

Answer (score 0):

Taking the "allowed area" from the view that contains the UIImageView

```
import UIKit

class DraggedImageView: UIImageView {

    var startLocation: CGPoint?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        startLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let currentLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self)
        let dx = currentLocation!.x - startLocation!.x
        let dy = currentLocation!.y - startLocation!.y

        let coolArea = (self.superview?.bounds)!

        let newCenter = CGPoint(x: self.center.x+dx, y: self.center.y+dy)

        // If the allowed area contains the new point, we can assign it
        if coolArea.contains(newCenter) {
            self.center = newCenter
            print("touchesMoved")
        }
         else {
            print("Out of boundaries!")
         }
    }
}
```